# How to get the previous list number of the removed paragraph

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-addins

I have a document with track changes enabled. For example:

[image]

I can find the actual list number of a list item by accessing the property `Paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString`. For paragraph 1 and 2 this property has values "1" and "2" appropriately. But when it comes to the paragraph 3 and paragraph 4 this property contains values "1" and "3" appropriately though the previous values were "3" and "4". Is there any other property or method in VSTO I could use in order to get the previous value of the `Paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString` property?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code which I use to extract the list numbers to clarify what I want to achieve.

```c#
var listParagraphs = Document.ListParagraphs.Cast<Paragraph>().ToList();
var actualListNumbers = new List<string>();
var previousListNumbers = new List<string>();

foreach(var paragraph in listParagraphs)
{
    actualListNumbers.Add(paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString);
    previousListNumbers.Add(?);
}

// actualListNumbers will contains the following values: 1, 2, 1, 3
// previousListNumbers should contain the following values: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Could you maybe share your code, explicitly where you use `Paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString`?

Comment: @UfguFugullu updated my question with the code example

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of research and came across [Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.revisions?view=word-pia). Here the old values can be read out. However, there seems to be an error in Microsoft Office, because [ListString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.listformat.liststring?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_ListFormat_ListString) always displays "1." for deleted list entries.

I tried to write a small class `ParagraphRevisionHolder` to read the previous values, but the error remains. If you know exactly what your lists look like, you may be able to write a workaround, for example by reading the index of the item.

In my example below I also read out the [type of change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.revision.type?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Revision_Type), so you can see if the list entry was deleted or edited.
I hope you find a solution to your problem. It would be nice if you could show it then here.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This function will be called on the start of this add in
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Event will be fired when a document was opened
    this.Application.DocumentOpen += ThisApplication_Open;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get all ListParagraphs of the opened document
/// </summary>
/// <param name="document">the opened document</param>
void ThisApplication_Open(Document document) {
    ListParagraphs listParagraphs = document.ListParagraphs;
    List<ParagraphRevisionHolder> list = new List<ParagraphRevisionHolder>();

    foreach(Paragraph paragraph in listParagraphs) {
        list.Add(new ParagraphRevisionHolder(paragraph.Range));
    }
}

class ParagraphRevisionHolder {

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns if revisions of the range does exist
    /// </summary>
    public bool RevisionsExist = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current ListString
    /// </summary>
    public string CurrentListString;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the current text
    /// </summary>
    public string CurrentText;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the ListString of the previous revision
    /// </summary>
    public string PreviousListString;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the text of the previous revision
    /// </summary>
    public string PreviousText;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the type of the revision
    /// </summary>
    public WdRevisionType PreviousRevisionType;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a collection of all revisions
    /// </summary>
    private Revisions Revisions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of this class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paragraphRange">the range of a paragraph</param>
    public ParagraphRevisionHolder(Range paragraphRange) {
        this.CurrentListString = paragraphRange.ListFormat.ListString;
        this.CurrentText = paragraphRange.Text;
        this.Revisions = paragraphRange.Revisions;

        this.GetPreviousText();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the data of the first revision
    /// </summary>
    private void GetPreviousText() {
        if (Revisions.Count > 0) {
            RevisionsExist = true;

            foreach(Revision revision in Revisions) {
                this.PreviousRevisionType = revision.Type;
                this.PreviousText = revision.Range.Text;

                // with the example document of your screenshot, revisions ListString always incorrectly returns "1."
                this.PreviousListString = revision.Range.ListFormat.ListString;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too hit this issue. More interestingly is when you delete the last (in your case) item in your list, then the deleted item retains it's original list number of 4.

My workaround in such case is:

1. Get the deleted paragraph marker and reject the deletion (somehow you have to do RejectAll as Revision(1) will reject the whole deleted list item)
2. After the RejectAll, listString will have changed from 1. to 3.
3. Get the the listString
4. Delete the paragraph marker again

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't want to edit the original document. Rejecting revision and then deleting a paragraph mark after this again would change the author of the revision.

Comment: you could ActiveDocument.Undo to get back to the original